# Getting sum value of a column having minimum date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data like this:

```
DATE                       ID        weight
----                      ----      -------
2017-04-25 11:05:42.273    247       0.418
2017-04-25 11:05:42.310    248       0.568
2017-04-25 13:57:55.327    247       0.418
2017-04-25 13:57:55.360    247       0.534
2017-04-25 13:57:55.397    248       0.568
2017-04-25 13:57:55.453    248       0.448
```

Now the requirement is I have to sum the gross weight based on barcodeid having minimum date.

here the output should be (0.418+0.568) because it has minimum date for barcode 247 and 248 respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a window function to assign a row number starting over for each partition (ID)
then only sum rownumber 1 a CTE or subquery is needed since RN would not be available to limit by.

A partition is just a grouping of records in the columns specified. so ID where 247 and 248 are different groups and row #1 will be assigned to the earliest date in each partition.  Then when we say where rn = 1 we only get weights for those earliest dates of each different ID!

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT A.* 
                    , Row_NUMBER() Over (Partition by ID order by Date asc) RN 
             FROM TABLE A)
SELECT Sum(Weight) 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Well I have egg on my face. Fixed

I believe a simple sub query will suffice

```
SELECT sum(weight)
FROM Table t1
WHERE DATE = (select min(DATE) from Table t2 where t1.ID = t2.ID group by id)
```

Comment: This does not produce the results the OP is looking for. This is the total of the smallest weight for each ID. They want the sum of weights for the earliest entry for each ID.

Comment: Not quite.  I think you need to group by the ID. otherwise you'll only get 1 min date right?

Comment: I actually took it out quickly but yeah not my day it seems.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte([DATE],ID,[weight])
AS
(

SELECT '2017-04-25 11:05:42.273', 247, 0.418 Union all
SELECT '2017-04-25 11:05:42.310', 248, 0.568 Union all
SELECT '2017-04-25 13:57:55.327', 247, 0.418 Union all
SELECT '2017-04-25 13:57:55.360', 247, 0.534 Union all
SELECT '2017-04-25 13:57:55.397', 248, 0.568 Union all
SELECT '2017-04-25 13:57:55.453', 248, 0.448
)
SELECT Sum(MinWeight) [SumOFweight] From
(
SELECT  ID,DATE,Min([weight])OVER(Partition by DATE) AS MinWeight ,Row_NUMBER() Over (Partition by ID order by Date asc) RN From
(
SELECT DATE,ID,SUM([weight])[weight]  FROM cte
GROUP by ID,DATE
)dt
)Final
where Final.RN=1
```

OutPut

```
SumOFweight
-------------
0.986
```